# Python format casts numpy.float32 into Python float

Tags: python, string, numpy, floating-point, formatting

I am outputting `numpy.float32` values and get the following:

```
> import numpy as np
> a = np.float32(0.1)
> a, str(a), repr(a)
(0.1, '0.1', '0.1')
> '{}'.format(a)
'0.10000000149011612'
> float(a)
0.10000000149011612
```

I would like `'{}'.format(a)` to return `'0.1'`.

So my questions are:

- Why does Python's `str.format` cast `numpy.float32` values to Python `float`s?
- Can I change some setting to have Python's `str.format` *not* cast `numpy.float32` values to Python `float`s?

In case this is relevant: I'm using Python 3.4.5 and numpy 1.10.4.

Comment: try `print('{:g}'.format(a))`

Comment: "Why does Python's str.format cast numpy.float32 values to Python floats?" <- It doesn't. The relevant code is in *NumPy*, not Python. Specifically `np.float32.__format__` inherits from `np.generic.__format__`, which *chooses* to convert to a regular Python float before applying formatting. This is entirely under NumPy's control. Code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b3f72f810ab1ef7142fc65dfe81c29e9bbba6328/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L396-L398

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks, while I wasn't able to follow the code, that is very informative. Can you make a full answer out of that? Perhaps including an approach to avoid the cast NumPy-side?

Answer (score 2):

Internally python uses 64bit floats. There is no way to change this. As with any floating point numbers, you have to know, how many digits are significant.

`float32` has at most 8 significant digits:

```
print "{:.8g}".format(a)
```

If you want to use numpy's string formatting, you have to explicitly cast to string:

```
print "{!s}".format(a)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer why `str.format` doesn't it just use `str(a)`? How can I avoid *this cast*? (I am aware of the floating point type issues involved, as indicated in my question, so that part of your answer may be dropped.)

Comment: `'{:!s}'.format(a)` gives `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`.

Comment: no `:` for `!s`. And this is the way, to force `format` to use `str(a)`.

Comment: @Daniel you get my upvote for the `{!s}` trick. Note that OP downvoted my answer, that's new (never saw that before except for a bogus answer) so consider yourself lucky.